# Getting my functions to run properly while working with objects

Tags: javascript, oop

I am creating a program which has an object called "Shoes". It has the properties of "Name", "ProductCode", "Quantitiy" and "ValuePerItem". I Have created 5 instances of "Shoes" and I have pushed them into an array. I want to create functions that will be able to determine whether or not a specific "Shoe" is in the Array, Which shoe has the highest Value per item, the lowest value per item, To be able to edit any insatnce of the shoes and a function to order them all in ascending order.

```
let myArray =[];

class Shoes{
    constructor(Name, ProductCode, Quantity, ValuePerItem){
        this.Name = Name,
        this.ProductCode = ProductCode,
        this.Quantity = Quantity,
        this.ValuePerItem = ValuePerItem    
    };
}

const shoe1 = new Shoes("Nike", "001", 500, 2000);
const shoe2 = new Shoes("Puma", "002", 1000, 1500);
const shoe3 = new Shoes("Adidas", "003", 250, 3000);
const shoe4 = new Shoes("Reebok", "004", 2500, 1000);
const shoe5 = new Shoes("Gucci", "005", 100, 5000);

myArray.push(shoe1, shoe2, shoe3, shoe4, shoe5);
console.log(myArray);

//This function goes through the values to determine whether or not that shoe brand is in the array or not
function findShoe(yes, item){
    for(let i = 0; i < yes.length; i++){
        if(yes[i] === item) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

let shoeName = "Nike";

console.log(findShoe(Shoes, shoeName))
```

Comment: Function `findShoe()` looks like it would be a great use case for [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Comment: You only explain your final goal, but not the problem(s) you're facing. I read your 'question' as "I want functions X, Y and Z, but only have X", which is surely not what you meant, so: What is your question?

Comment: From this and your previous questions it becomes clear that you keep trying to solve 10 problems at the same time. It may help you to identify one main problem first and then try to solve it. If that fails you can ask a question here about that one specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

you should pass array of Shoes class instances, instead Shoes class

```
findShoe(myArray, shoeName)
```

in the findShoe function you should compare instance property "Name"

```
function findShoe(array, item){
 let isFound = false
 for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  if(array[i].Name === item){
   isFound = true;
   break;
  };
 }
 return isFound;
}
```

Comment: You could have kept the return statement in the for-loop. No reason to loop over all elements once a match is found.